# How to select whole sheet and put it in a textbox in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have a excel sheet and a form. I want to select all the entries from the sheet and put it in a ListBox in my form. how to do that

I have selected the sheet using

```
Private Sub view_Change()
Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Select
view.Text = .Value
End Sub
```

Now I dont know how to put the selection in a ListBox

Comment: SO it is not a supplier of code ready to use.
try yourself and put here your test, we will be happy to help you

Comment: Sorry... I have added the code

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to do it using

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

ListBox1.ColumnWidths = "92;140;110;65;"
ListBox1.ColumnCount = 12
ListBox1.List = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("a2:l" & [a65536].End(3).Row).Value

End Sub
```